# Lock video header to top of webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm building a web page with the typical horizontal sections going down the page. I want to put an mp4 video at the top of the page. To get it to stay the top (And not have things under it overlap it) I set:

```html
<div id="home" class="section full-width full-screen">
  <video poster="img/default.png" preload="auto" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" class="header-video">
    <source src="vid/promo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="video-wrap" style="z-index: 0;">
    <div class="video-overlay" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.header-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

and this is what it looks like:

[image: video header normal browser size]

but if I shrink the browser width, I get this:

[image: video header shrunken width]

How do I get it to stay at the top when the browser is resized?

Edit: I got it with:

```css
.header-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

but now the content underneath has moved way up ontop of the video. What's the best/proper way to push it down?

[image: content clipping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `object-fill` from `fill` to `cover`.

The final code should look like this:

```css
.header-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```